# Как настроить java сервер на получение внешнего json запроса

Tags: java, сервер, http, servlet

Пытаюсь отправить Post запросом через Postman следующее значение

{
    "categoryId":"2",
    "id":"1"
}
Java сервер примерно такой

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/MyServlet")
```

public class HttpClient extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int categoryId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("categoryId"));
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    System.out.println(categoryId);
    System.out.println(id);

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h3>Привет от " + categoryId + " и " + id + "</h3>");
    out.close();
}
```

}

Не знаю как настроить его на получение json файла

Comment: а как вы его запускаете? для сервлета нужен контейнер сервлетов, например, томкат

Comment: да, использую томкат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш JSON будет в теле запроса, и прочитать его можно вот так:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class GetBodyServlet extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            int readChars;
            try(Reader reader = req.getReader()){
                while ((readChars=reader.read(buffer))!=-1){
                    body.append(buffer,0, readChars);
                }
            }
            // в body лежит json
            System.out.println(body.toString());
        }

}
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо! я над этим 4 дня парился